# How can I use tailwindcss without internet?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, offline

How can I compile and use tailwind css while offline? As in, have the full tailwind css and purge it to only what I require for my website, like normal, but with no internet access.

I'm definitely inexperienced in tailwind, so I first tried to just get the full css file, but I was unable to even get that far. I tried with these terminal commands:

`npm install tailwindcss`

`npx tailwindcss init`

`npx tailwindcss build styles.css -o output.css`

Which gave me a partial file, given that styles.css contained:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Comment: You can install tailwind locally, like you do with `npm`. You don't need internet after that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you followed the steps in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation?

You didnt' mention whether you created a `tailwind.config.js` for your project. This file is important, as it defines the which files in which to look for class names when it comes to the purging of unused classes:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

If you run the build command, it should give you a CSS file with all the classes that are in use in your .html and .js files.

Show us what the content of your `output.css` looks like to help you debug this issue further.

Answer (score -1):

you should go to this link `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.16/dist/tailwind.min.css`

then `Ctrl + s` to save the page content with name `tailwindmain.css`
and save this in your `public/css` directory

to use it in the top of your blade or in your layout you should do that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/tailwindmain.css')}}">
```

and that's perfectly work inshaala , and you should good to go .

Comment: That does not provide equivalent functionality as they were getting in the question.